# To add widgets from the app drawer, launchers need to be installed in /system. Why?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher

ICS' stock launcher, Apex, Nova and Trebuchet all support adding widgets by dragging them from the app drawer. However they can only do this if they are installed as a system app. One of them - I think Nova - also provides a helper app that can be installed in /system while the rest of the app remains a regular app.

Why can't normally installed launchers provide this feature?

Comment: I don't think anyone except the developers of these launchers will be able to answer this.  I would suggest contacting them directly with this feature request.

Comment: This is not a feature request, this is a question why something is impossible.

Comment: I have clarified question title. If you don't like it, feel free to roll back.